# Raspberry Pi remap DPI pins

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, display, device-tree

I'm trying to hook up my Raspberry Pi a to custom display hat via the parallel display interface (GPIO Pins, not ribbon cable). The problem I'm facing is that the DPI pins are rather awkwardly placed on the GPIO header. This is an issue because of my form factor constraints. I'd like to keep my package rather small, so I decided to mount the display to a PCB, which is attached in a hat-like fashion to the Raspberry Pi. The way the pins are laid out on my screen and the Raspberry Pi makes routing the signals, even on a two layer PCB, quite a pain.

Is there a way to reassign some of the DPI pins to a different physical pin? I've looked into the device tree overlay but couldn't find anything o the sort.

I plan on using a Raspberry Pi Zero W if that should make any difference.

Thanks!

Edit: To clear things up am referring to [these pins](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324184819/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/dpi/dpi-altfn2.png) as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#parallel-display-interface-dpi). I know that there are not many other pins left but simply being able to rearrange them would make life a lot easier.

Comment: What are the DPI pins?  See https://pinout.xyz/ Whatever they are it's highly unlikely they can be routed elsewhere.

Comment: When i said DPI i was referring to the Parallel Display Interface.

Comment: You need to edit your question and include a photo showing which pins you wish to use and where you wish to use them.

Comment: google `arm cortex-a53 redefine pins` .... you may find something useful